# Automatically scan RSS feeds and populate WebContent model

Tags: python, json, django, rss

I am trying to create a Django server application (currently on local host) that will routinely check given RSS feeds provided by the model `Blogger` (i.e. once every hour), extract data from then provide data for the model `WebContent`.

So far I have created a data endpoint at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/blogger/` which outputs the following information:

```
[
    {
        "id": "c384f191-662f-43f9-a39d-2da737e7cbb8",
        "name": "Patricia Bright",
        "avatar": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/img/1470305802086_IMG_5921.JPG",
        "rss_url": "http://patriciabright.co.uk/?feed=rss2",
    },
    {
        "id": "dc70ca6b-94cc-4ba9-a0c8-0d907f7ab020",
        "name": "Shirley B. Eniang",
        "avatar": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/img/1470305797487_photo.jpg",
        "rss_url": "http://shirleyswardrobe.com/feed/",
    }
]
```

Now I would like to loop through the `rss_url` value above and extract particular information from each RSS feed to provide data for the model `WebContent`. I want to run this hourly, and a check should be made to see if the data already exists before populating the model `WebContent` (so I don't get any duplicate requests).

This is what I've done so far in `models.py`:

```
from uuid import uuid4
from time import time
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
import feedparser


def get_upload_avatar_path(instance, filename):
    timestamp = int(round(time() * 1000))
    path = "img/%s_%s" % (timestamp, filename)
    return path


class Blogger(models.Model):
    """
    Blogger model
    """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_avatar_path, blank=True, null=True, default=None, max_length=255)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    rss_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    instagram_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    twitter_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    youtube_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Bloggers"

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.name)

    def generate_web_content(self):
        """
        Scan for blogger RSS feeds and generate web content
        :return: None
        """
        web_content = WebContent.objects.create(user_profile=self)
        self._scan_web_content(web_content)

    def _scan_web_content(self, web_content=None):
        """
        Scan blogger RSS feeds
        :param report: Associated WebContent object
        :return: None
        """
        urls = Blogger.objects.all()
        d = feedparser.parse(urls['rss_url'])
        for post in d.entries:
            blogger = self
            title = post.title.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
            url = post.link.encode('ascii', 'ignore')


class WebContent(models.Model):
    """
    Model to store blogger web content
    """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    blogger = models.ForeignKey(Blogger)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Web Content"
```

I've managed to mockup an implementation in a seperate python file which works well. I guess I am trying to port that into my Django application.

```
import feedparser
import json
import sys
import os


os.system('cls')


# Import json
with open('bloggers.json') as jsonfile:
    j = json.load(jsonfile)


for blogger in j['bloggers']:
    print (blogger['name'])
    print "---------------------"

    d = feedparser.parse(blogger['rssUrl'])
    for post in d.entries:
        print post.title.encode('ascii', 'ignore') + ": " + post.link.encode('ascii', 'ignore') + "\n"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be many problems in your code:

1. Within the method `generate_web_content` you are creating a `WebContent` object by passing the argument `user_profile=self` while it should be `blogger=self`.
2. In the method `_scan_web_content` you've queried all the `Blogger` objects like:

   ```
   urls = Blogger.objects.all()
   ```

   so, `urls` is a queryset object and you can't access the key like `urls['rss_url']` instead you should do

   ```
   d = feedparser.parse(self.rss_url)
   ```
3. Inside the for loop you should add attributes to the `WebContent` object passed as an argument like:

   ```
   for post in d.entries:
       web_content.blogger = self
       web_content.title = post.title.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
       web_content.url = post.link.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
   web_content.save()
   ```

   otherwise this method does not do anything.

Hope it clarifies!